# How to use Pixi.js in a Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pixi.js

I want to add Pixi.js to one of my VueJs components, but it doesn't work. What I want to do for now is to implement one of the basic examples from the Pixi.js website.

The problem is that with the same code as the one on the website, I only see the background color on my screen.

Here is my VueJS component:

```
<template>
<body>
<div id='change'>    
    <router-link class="changepage" to='/OrdreCouches'> >Retour </router-link>    
</div>
  <div id="pixi"></div>
</body>
</template>



<script>
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

export default {
  name: 'Visualisation',
  data(){
    return{
      app: new PIXI.Application()
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      const app = new PIXI.Application({
          width: 800, height: 600, backgroundColor: 0x1099bb, resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
      });
      document.body.appendChild(app.view);

      const container = new PIXI.Container();

      app.stage.addChild(container);

      // Create a new texture
      const texture = PIXI.Texture.from('./assets/blob.png');

      // Create a 5x5 grid of bunnies
      for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
          const bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
          bunny.anchor.set(0.5);
          bunny.x = (i % 5) * 40;
          bunny.y = Math.floor(i / 5) * 40;
          container.addChild(bunny);
      }

      // Move container to the center
      container.x = app.screen.width / 2;
      container.y = app.screen.height / 2;

      // Center bunny sprite in local container coordinates
      container.pivot.x = container.width / 2;
      container.pivot.y = container.height / 2;

      // Listen for animate update
      app.ticker.add((delta) => {
          // rotate the container!
          // use delta to create frame-independent transform
          container.rotation -= 0.01 * delta;
      });
  }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
  
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.changepage{
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 30px;
}
.changepage:hover{
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(53, 20, 199);
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Could you help me with this?

Thank you!!

Comment: I think this SO post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780010/how-to-load-a-pixi-instance-in-vuejs

Comment: @MicFung I have tried what they suggest on this post but I can't get it to work

Comment: I am not familiar with the library. just make a demo for you. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-panini-pxzcb?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue dont know if it is what you want